# POST without Submit and Fill Input Field With The Temporary Data From The POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i got some problem here with the code, the idea is to post some card number and get the information about the person from other server API and then using a button to fill some input field identified by input ID with the data i got from the API without saving it to database.

Current step:

1. PHP Form (1.php) -> Worked
2. Inputing Card Number -> Worked
3. Submit The Card Number With Ajax To Other PHP File To Get Response From API (2.php, i also echo the result here) -> Worked
4. Div Popup (Containing the response echoed from 2.php) -> Worked
5. Using some button to populate the data from 2.php into 1.php multiple input field <- the problem is here

1.php

```
<script>
function checkcard()
    {
    var name=document.getElementById('card').value;
    var dataString='card='+ name;                                    
        $.ajax({                                     
               type:"POST",
               url:"../loader/2.php",                                
               data:dataString,                                  
               cache:false,
           success: function(html){
              $('#msg').html(html);
           }
    }) return false;    
       }
</script>

<div>
  <label class="col-form-label"><b>Card Number</b></label><br>                                       
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="card" name="card">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="return 
  checkcard()">Check
</button>

<div id="msg">
</div>

<label class="col-form-label"><b>NICK</b></label><br>                                           

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nick" name="nick">

<script type="text/javascript">                                                   
  function autoFill() {                                                      
  document.getElementById('nick').value = <?php echo json_encode($nick); ?>;
}    </script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="autoFill(); return true;">
```

The Autofill function and button is in 1.php and when i click the button, nothing happened, i also have tried to put it inside 2.php but when i click the button, the page refreshed/reload and the response is gone, any idea how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `<?php echo json_encode($nick); ?>` in `1.php` you are recoursing back to PHP which is not useful except you submit the entire `1.php` file back to the server for PHP preprocessing.

Remember, you have already retrieved the data of `2.php` via ajax. You can store that data in a global variable so it is accessible to the entire `1.php`.

This is a recast of `1.php`

```
<div>
  <label class="col-form-label"><b>Card Number</b></label><br>                                       
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="card" name="card">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="return 
  checkcard()">Check
</button>

<div id="msg">
</div>

<label class="col-form-label"><b>NICK</b></label><br>                                           

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nick" name="nick">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return autoFill()">

<script type="text/javascript">     
    var global_data = '';

    function checkcard()
    {
        var name = $('#card').val();
        var dataString ='card='+ name;                                   
        $.ajax({                                     
            type:"POST",
            url:"../loader/2.php",                               
            data:dataString,                                     
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                global_data = data;
                $('#msg').html(data);
           }
        }) 
        return false;   
    }                   

    function autoFill() {                                                        
        $('#nick').val(global_data);
        return false;
    }    
</script>
```

Notice I'm using jQuery `val()` method instead of JavaScript `value` property and I'm returning false for both `checkcard()` and `autoFill()` functions to avoid page refresh.

Comment: thank you so much! now its worked as i hope, except its fill the input with everything that i echoed in 2.php :D but thats something that i must edit in 2.php, thank you once again

Comment: Welcome @ary431. You can also upvote this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**NICK**

function autofill(){


    var name=$('#nick').val();       

    windows.location.href = "../loader/1.php"?name=" + name;


}